# Android set textcolor of actionbar, example not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This has been posted before but I still cannot figure it out. I want to change the text color of my actionbar, preferrably programmatically (is that even possible?).

I looked at examples at:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html
but I get "or: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Holo'."

I am using For Android 3.0 and higher only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>
    ...
```

Isn't there a simpler way to do it? I mean you can get the actionbar but there seems to be no method .setTextColor, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
parent="@style/Theme.Holo"
```

use

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a Theme.Holo in your style directory? Else you might want to use @android:style/Theme.Holo